# Why is "www.example.com" not the same as "example.com"?

Tags: php, web-applications

I have a website. If I login in the domain of this format http://example.com and then change my address to http://www.example.com, i find my account is not logged in. If I change the address to http://example.com, I find my account is logged in.

I contacted my host, they told me its a programming issue.

How can i solve this issue so both addresses represent same access/session/cookies?

I'm using PHP & MySQL

Comment: And you set the cookie available to all domains by using a slash as the domain path. See `setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600, "/", ".example.com", 1);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`www.example.com` and `example.com` are two different domains as far as the browser is concerned, apparently, even though they both direct to the same site. Same would happen if you parked a different domain there, say, `example.net`.

In order to solve the issue, it is rather common to rewrite the URL via .htaccess. Decide upon which domain name you prefer to use and add something like this to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301]
```

(the first one removes, the second one adds the www)

Comment: This also saves you headaches if you decide you want to switch to HTTPS, and SEO people I've worked with in the past have mentioned that this helps avoid getting dinged for "duplicate content" by search engines.

Comment: Well, the dupe content issue can be avoided by using a canonical URL, but your remark is still a valid one, thanks :).

Answer (score 6):

> How can i solve this issue so both addresses represent same
>   access/session/cookies?

You have to set the domain path of your cookie like this to make it available on all subdomains: (www is a subdomain):

`.domain.com`

Comment: Any domain with www prefix are usually termed as NAKED DOMAIN

Answer (score -1):

It is not same..
usually you can go to www.example.com just with writing example.com to your browser, but your browser added www to your url..
so basicly it is not same

Comment: An accurate assessment, but it doesn't provide any actionable information to help solve the OP (I'm guessing this is why this answer got downvoted).