# example.com and www.example.com are treated as different sessions

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

So i have a small website that requires users to log in with a username and password.
Everything works fine apart from 1 tiny problem

when the user logs in using the url  [studeez.net](http://studeez.net/), he or she is redirected to a page where the top bar displays his Firstname, lastname and an option to logout.

But if i add www. before the link so that it becomes [www.studeez.net](http://www.studeez.net), the user is given the login /register options.

This is quite the issue because when the user tries to log in, he or she gets a feedback that they are already logged in.

How do i harmonize studeez.net and www.studeez.net as well as all the subsequent urls like studeez.ney/path/to/page and www.studeez.ney/path/to/page

Comment: It could be due to the cookies being set for non-www domain only.

Comment: @anubhava i am not using any cookies as of now

Comment: ok see if below answer works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to force the `www` or `no-www` to keep user session on the same site. You can use this htaccess condition to rewrite to the correct domain. This example will force the use of `www`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076742/why-is-www-example-com-not-the-same-as-example-com?rq=1).

Comment: thank you, but does this work well for the subsequent urls like

studeez.net/path/to/page/   and      www.studeez.net/path/to/page/

Comment: What his example does is change the domain from `example.com` to `www.example.com` and all the `/path/to/page` stuff remains unchanged, so basically if someone where to visit `http://example.com/some/page` they would actually be redirected to `http://www.example.com/some/page`.

Comment: @JohnKariuki yes it will, as txpeace mentionned.

Answer (score 0):

Baring using .htaccess files or modifying the server configuration to use mod_rewrite, this should work fine as a pure PHP solution:

```
$sname = session_name(); // Get the name of the session cookie.
if ( !isset($_SESSION) ) session_start(); // If a session has not been started then start one.
$sid = ( isset($_COOKIE[$sname]) ) ? session_id($_COOKIE[$sname]) : session_id();  // Get an encrypted session identifier.
setcookie($sname, $sid, time()+86400, "/", ".example.com", false, true); // Set the .example.com cookie so we can work across all sub-domains.
```

Change the .example.com to whatever your domain name is in the .**domain.tld** format without a sub-domain, but including the period at the beginning.  This should set a cookie which works across all sub-domains of your domain.